# pass UIImage with a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, segue

I want to pass an UIImage between two view with a segue. The problem is that my UIImage appear white in the second view controller.

The segue :

```
var screenShot = UIImage()

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "screenshotEmbed") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! screenshotViewController
        svc.toPass = self.screenshot
    }
```

The secondViewController :

```
class screenshotViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var screenshotView: UIImageView!
var toPass = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.screenshotView.image = self.toPass        
}
```

}

My UIImage is just a screenshot, here the function :

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage {
    var window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0]
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window!.frame.size, window!.opaque, 0.0)
    window!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image;
}
```

EDIT. Screenshot storage on a button :

```
@IBAction func photoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.screenShot = captureScreen()
}
```

I've tried lot of thing but still blank (not empty cause the memory adress is good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your `screenshotImage` object has Image or not.

I tried below code and it's working fine.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "screenshotEmbed") {
            let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ScreenshotViewController
            svc.toPass = captureScreen()
        }
    }

    func captureScreen() -> UIImage {
        var window: UIWindow? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0]
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(window!.frame.size, window!.opaque, 0.0)
        window!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image;
    }

}
```

Result with this code:

[image]

Project [Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/file_uploaded.php?file_id=01241482113596560255&del_id=79759231807809467552&gk=laptop) for more Info.

Comment: screenshotImage is an UIImage for sur. That's weird. If i do svc.toPass = capture() it works too.. but i've to store on screenshotImage. I'll edit the post with screenshoteImage storage

Comment: your `screenshotImage` object has any Image?

Comment: Nice one, that was the problem my IBAction(where i store the screenShot) was on AnyObject and not on UIbutton. I think it's still weird but it works now...

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

in second scene you should modified the property to

```
var toPass: UIImage!
```

because in second scene you initial the image to UIImage()